# materialized / meteor - select form is not working

Tags: meteor, materialized

I'm trying to use materialized select form on my Meteor app but it seems not working....

Here is my code:

### html

```
<template name="createAutomatedaction">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
      <label>Materialize Select</label>
    </div>
</template>
```

### js

```
Template.createAutomatedaction.onRendered(function(){
  this.$('select').material_select();
});
```

When I click select form, dropdown doesn't show up. Could anyone advise me what i'm missing by any chance? Your help would be really appreciated.

with *this*
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzh7sp5x7by6e1t/Screenshot%202015-05-09%2018.20.54.png?dl=0

without *this*
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1asl3y5pbtg5yp/Screenshot%202015-05-09%2018.24.08.png?dl=0

Comment: Without 'this.' it's not working aswell?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you can see (I edited my question), with this shows select form and without this doesn't show select form...so without this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code to initialize the select is this (assuming 'createAutomatedaction' is your template's name)

```
Template.createAutomatedaction.onRendered(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

If you are using the last (at the time of writing) version of materialize (v0.97.2) [there is a bug that causes the dropdown not to be generated](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2265) fixed on [this commit](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/commit/45feae64410252fe51e56816e664c09d83dc8931).

If you want to quickly fix it manually, grab the unminified js from their repo (dist/js/materialize.js) and replace every instance of '$body' for 'bodyElement' and use that.

Selects will work.

Answer (score 0):

Place your jquery code in a template event:

```
Template.templatename.events({
      this.$('select').material_select();
});
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Adding `class="browser-default"` in the `select` tag worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I removed `class="input-field"` and it worked for me.